# One ethernet cable or should I install more?

Tags: ethernet, bandwidth

I have two cctv cameras, a tv and my desktop pc that I want to connect to the router about 20m away by ethernet. Will a single cable do with an unmanaged switch or should I install two or even more. I am specifically thinking about speed, will one cable be able to handle everything if all those items were trying to shift large amounts of data? Would one cable be a bottleneck? My internet connection is 40Mps Thank you for helping

Comment: What makes you think the router isn't sharing a single controller for all its ports? Or the switch, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> will one cable be able to handle everything if all those items were trying to shift large amounts of data?... My internet connection is 40Mps

Cat5e cables support up to 1000 Mbps so even one cable support much more than your bandwidth.

Still if your router has four free ports it's a good idea to run four cables as that means one device less i.e. less chance for failure

Comment: Thank you Mate for your help.  I'll put in two to fill the two vacant ports on the router.